# where to find documentation about order of sections

Tags: freepascal, lazarus

Consider this code:

```
unit uglobals;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface
const
     BORD_WIDTH = 8;
uses
  Classes, SysUtils;

implementation

end.
```

Compilator show me error:

> uglobals.pas(8,1) Fatal: Syntax error, "IMPLEMENTATION" expected but "USES" found

Because obviously `const` section must be after `uses` section.

Where can I find documentation which gives the order of sections?

I've searched in Google and freepascal.org but I did not find anything about the required order of the sections.

Comment: Did google not find you this https://wiki.freepascal.org/Unit?

Comment: The page you redirect do not mention the order of sections. Perhaps the best page is the official documentation but I find the diagram not very clear https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/current/ref/refse112.html#x233-25700016.2

Comment: See the "interface part" line. after "interface" comes the uses block, and only then const/type/var/property/procedure. These railroad diagrams are BNFify.

Comment: What means "BNFify" ?

Comment: bnf-like, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form

Comment: Googling for ***pascal syntax*** should probably have been your first impulse, because you can find it here: **`uses`** can be seen **in three places**: 1) after the `program` statement in programs and in units 2) after `interface` or 3) after `implementation`.